# Move all content to new subfolder

Tags: linux, shell

I have a shell script for linux that lives in the base-level folder `testing` and will go into the `original` directory, copy everything to the `input` folder, and then within each subdirectory in `input` perform three tasks:

1. Create a new folder called `tip`
2. Put all of the files within into `tip`
3. Create a second new folder called `sorted`

When I tested it on the command line, the only issue I got was that since I created the `tip` folder before moving everything into it, it bounces back an error that it can't move a folder within itself--which is fine, whatever. But, when I run it in NiFi it gives me a different error (`cannot create directory tip: file exists`) and behaves differently.

**Script**

```
#!/bin/bash

# copy to input while maintaining file structure
cd /data/testing/original
cp -r * /data/testing/input
cd /data/testing/input

# for each subfolder in input, create tip & sorted, and move all of the original stuff into tip
for dir in /data/testing/input/*
do
  test -d "$dir" || continue
  cd "$dir" && mkdir tip && mv * tip/
  mkdir sorted
done
```

**Expected Output in each subfolder in** `/data/testing/input/subfolder/`

```
sorted -> empty
tip -> media folder, file1, file2
```

**Actual Output**

```
sorted -> empty
tip -> media folder, file1, file2
media folder
file1
file2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you check your output / How do you validate it ?
I hope you are aware that at the end you are still in the last `$dir` from you loop.

Comment: @deimus I am looking in the $dir directory and can see what the output is. Yes, I want it to be operating in the $dir folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
shopt -s extglob 

# trailing slash forces the results to be dirs
# ..............................v
for dir in /data/testing/input/*/; do 
  (
    cd "$dir" && mkdir tip sorted && mv -t tip/ !(tip|sorted)
    # ..........................................^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    #               anything *not* matching "tip" or "sorted"
  )
  # run above in a subshell so you don't have to cd back to parent dir
done
```